# Вывод данных из QListWidget

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt5

Как вывести данные из `ListWidget`?

Как правильно чтобы при выборе, коннект происходил через `.clicked.connect(s)`?

```
def s():
  c=lista.text()
  print(c)
lista=QListWidget(root)
lista.move(200,200)
lista.resize(400,400)
lista.addItems(['1','2'])
lista.itemClicked.connect(s)
```

Comment: В смысле вывести? В консоль что ли напечатать? Или в файлик сохранить? Про выбор и коннест тоже не понятно что имеется ввиду

Comment: @gil9red вывод в консоль

Comment: А я уже ответил на опережение :D

Comment: @gil9red с телефона не просто за этим следить) добавил в вопрос комментарий вот в моем случае возникает ошибка почему вроде как вывод текста text()

Comment: Ну вам бы прикладывать заодно и текст ошибки :) Но я и так скажу: `lista` это `QListWidget`, а у него нет метода `text`

Comment: @gil9red сложные приколы конечно) Спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В этом ответе:

- Добавил примеры работы с [QListWidget](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlistwidget.html) и данными в ней, функции: `fill_list_widget`, `print_list_widget`, `get_list_from_list_widget`.
- Добавил пример сохранения данных в файл (формат json) приведен после заполнения виджета-списка.
- Добавил пример обработки клика на элементы списка приведен в строке `lw.itemClicked.connect(_on_item_clicked)`
- В качестве бонуса, добавил пример обработки не пойманных исключений

---

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *


def log_uncaught_exceptions(ex_cls, ex, tb):
    text = '{}: {}:\n'.format(ex_cls.__name__, ex)
    import traceback
    text += ''.join(traceback.format_tb(tb))

    print(text)
    QMessageBox.critical(None, 'Error', text)
    sys.exit()


sys.excepthook = log_uncaught_exceptions


def fill_list_widget(lw: QListWidget):
    for i in range(10):
        lw.addItem('Item #{}'.format(i))


def print_list_widget(lw: QListWidget):
    print('Items ({}):'.format(lw.count()))

    for i in range(lw.count()):
        item = lw.item(i)
        print('    {}'.format(item.text()))


def get_list_from_list_widget(lw: QListWidget) -> list:
    items = []

    for i in range(lw.count()):
        item = lw.item(i)
        items.append(item.text())

    return items


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])

    def _on_item_clicked(item: QListWidgetItem):
        print('Item clicked:', item.text())

    lw = QListWidget()
    lw.itemClicked.connect(_on_item_clicked)

    lw.show()

    print_list_widget(lw)
    fill_list_widget(lw)
    print_list_widget(lw)

    items = get_list_from_list_widget(lw)
    print('Items:', items)

    with open('list_widget.json', mode='w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        import json
        json.dump(items, f, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False)

    app.exec()
```

В консоли:

```
Items (0):
Items (10):
    Item #0
    Item #1
    Item #2
    Item #3
    Item #4
    Item #5
    Item #6
    Item #7
    Item #8
    Item #9
Items: ['Item #0', 'Item #1', 'Item #2', 'Item #3', 'Item #4', 'Item #5', 'Item #6', 'Item #7', 'Item #8', 'Item #9']
```